# Error Code while using Pivot in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Presently solving a challenge question and i have been trying to solve the issue i am facing but unable to do so. Your expertise would be highly appreciated.

Here is the question:

Pivot the Occupation column in OCCUPATIONS so that each Name is sorted alphabetically and displayed underneath its corresponding Occupation. The output column headers should Doctor, Professor, Singer, and Actor, respectively.

**My Solution**

```
SELECT
    [Doctor],
    [Professor],
    [Singer],
    [Actor]
FROM
    (SELECT 
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Occupation ORDER BY Name) ma,
         [Name],
         [Occupations] 
     FROM 
         Occupation
    ) AS source 
PIVOT
    ( MAX([Name]) FOR [occupation] IN ([Doctor],[Professor],[Singer],[Actor]) ) as pv
ORDER BY ma
```

**Error Message**

```
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 5: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '[Doctor],
    [Professor],
    [Singer],
    [Actor]
FROM
    (SELECT 
         ' at line 2
```

Awaiting your replies. Thanks

Comment: `Mysql` does not support `PIVOT` operator

Comment: You use `SQL Server` syntax.

Answer (score 4):

`Mysql` does not support `PIVOT` operator

use `conditional aggregate` to pivot the data.

Since the names are split into 4 different columns, Ordering by name after pivoting the data does not make lot of sense.

```
select 
Occupations,
max(case when occupation = 'Doctor' then name end) as Doctor,
max(case when occupation = 'Professor' then name end) as Professor,
max(case when occupation = 'Singer' then name end) as Singer,
max(case when occupation = 'Actor' then name end) as Actor
from Occupation
Group by Occupations
```

Also instead of square brackets `[]` you should use backticks ``` `` ```

Comment: Thanks. Solved it using Oracle

Answer (score 0):

For Mysql , you can solve it this way:

```
set @d=0, @p=0, @s=0, @a=0;

select min(Doctor), min(Professor), min(Singer), min(Actor)
from(
  select case 
            when Occupation='Doctor' then (@d:=@d+1)
            when Occupation='Professor' then (@p:=@p+1)
            when Occupation='Singer' then (@s:=@s+1)
            when Occupation='Actor' then (@a:=@a+1) 
            end as Rowline,
        case when Occupation='Doctor' then Name end as Doctor,
        case when Occupation='Professor' then Name end as Professor,
        case when Occupation='Singer' then Name end as Singer,
        case when Occupation='Actor' then Name end as Actor
  from OCCUPATIONS
  order by Name
) as temp
group by Rowline;
```

Hope this will resolve your issue.